# fovis on depth-only sensors?

Tags: ros, depth-registered, depth, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I wanted to implement SLAM on Occipital's Structure Sensor which happens to be a depth only camera and provides no RGB images.

I was wondering if there is anyway to use the Fovis package to obtain odometry from Structure despite the fact that it subscribes to /rgb/image_rect

Is there any remapping etc that can be utilized for this or is that RGB frame crucial for odom calculation?

this is the error I get

Images received:            0 (topic '/camera/rgb/image_color')
Depth images received:      33082 (topic '/camera/depth/image')
Image camera info received: 0 (topic '/camera/rgb/camera_info')
Depth camera info received: 33082 (topic '/camera/depth/camera_info')
Synchronized tuples: 0

Or if there is any other option to perform 2D slam on structure sensor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199999/fovis-on-depth-only-sensors?/) by [VijethRai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21212/vijethrai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VijethRai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21212/vijethrai/) on 2014-12-27**:
Hey,

Any input will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*libfovis* uses *FAST* features to track images. A color image is required to use it. [Read the article.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/pubs/2011-huang-isrr.pdf)

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1